# CWE-73: External Control of File Name or Path

Tags: spring-boot, security, spring-batch, owasp, veracode

I'm having issues with CWE-73 regarding parentDir reaching the unzip method.

This class is responsible for unzipping the file and returning the address/name of the file in a temporary folder. I've researched a lot about validations, but no version is accepted in the Veracode Scan. Could you help me?

The vulnerability CWE-73 is pointed out in the line

`Path entryPath = parentDir.resolve(entryName).toAbsolutePath().normalize();`

Method that calls the class that will unzip the file:

```
private String criaEdescompactaArquivo(String fileName, byte[] report) throws IOException {
    String extractedFileName;
    var decodedFile = new DecodedMultipartFile(report, fileName);
    var file = Files.createTempFile(fileName, ".zip");
    decodedFile.transferTo(file);
    extractedFileName = UnzipFileHelper.unzip(file.toFile());
    return extractedFileName;
}
```

Class that will unzip the file and return the address/name of the file in the temporary folder:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.zip.;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class UnzipFileHelper {

    private UnzipFileHelper() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Utility class");
    }
    
    public static String unzip(File file) throws IOException {
        return unzip(file, file.getParentFile().toPath());
    }
    
    private static String unzip(File file, Path parentDir) throws IOException {
        if (!Files.isDirectory(parentDir)) {
            throw new SecurityException("Parent directory is not valid");
        }
        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
            if (Objects.isNull(zipEntry)) {
                return null;
            }
            String entryName = zipEntry.getName();
            if (entryName.contains("..") || entryName.contains(File.separator)) {
                throw new SecurityException("Invalid file name");
            }
            Path entryPath = parentDir.resolve(entryName).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
            log.info("Unzip: entryPath = {}", entryPath);
    
            if (!entryPath.startsWith(parentDir)) {
                throw new SecurityException("Invalid file path");
            }
    
            final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = (long) 100 * 1_024 * 1_024;
            if (zipEntry.getSize() > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                throw new SecurityException("File size exceeds maximum allowed");
            }
    
            Files.createDirectories(entryPath.getParent());
    
            try (OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(entryPath)) {
                final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = zis.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) >= 0) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, length);
                }
            }
            zis.closeEntry();
            return entryPath.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Changes needed to mitigate this vulnerability.